# Set Rails object value to true on onclick method in html

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, material-design

I have created a checkbox in html(materialize) and now after I click on the checkbox, I want to set a Ruby Object to true.

Is there any way to do this. Could we also use Js for it. I would even be up for a hacky solution for now.

```
#_form.html.erb


<%= form_with(model: export_application, local: true, html: {multipart: true}, id: "export-application-portal") do |form| %>

    <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
        <label>Haben Sie schon einmal Hermesdeckungen genutzt?</label>

        <p>
        <label for="Hermes-y">
            <input type="checkbox" class="yes yes-no-btns"  id="export_application_has_previously_used_hermes_cover" name="export_application[has_previously_used_hermes_cover]" value="true"/>
            <span class="yes yes-no-btns" onclick="previouslyHermesInsuranceUsed()" > Yes</span>
        </label>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
        <input class="handex-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Antrag Shicken">
    </div>
<% end %>

function previouslyHermesInsuranceUsed() {
    var x = document.getElementById("newAtHermesDeckung");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I have been trying for hours and hours but to no avail.

Comment: Is your form backed by a Rails model? Also could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve. It sounds like this might not be the best way to go about things.

Comment: Yes the backend is Rails Model. Why do you think its not a best way to go forward.
Its a form that I have created in rails in which I am calling this code.

Comment: Also in rails with Material design, its hard to sort out the checkboxes.

Comment: Well, normally you would have an attribute on the model (`has_previously_used_hermes_cover`, I guess, in your case) which is set/updated when the form is submitted. Are you trying to update this without a form submission (via Ajax) and use this value to do something else on the page? This is what I meant with "might not be the best way to go about things". For me it's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, I am not doing ajax, Its a just a simple ruby form where fields are updated when submitted.

Comment: So you have a model with a `has_previously_used_hermes_cover` property on it which can be set to true or false. You are trying to create a form for this model which has a check box corresponding to the `has_previously_used_hermes_cover` property. When the check box is checked and the form is submitted, `has_previously_used_hermes_cover` should be set to `true`. When the check box is _not_ checked and the form is submitted, `has_previously_used_hermes_cover` should be set to `false`. Did I get that right?